# How to get $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2=\int e^{\lambda}d\sigma(\lambda)$?

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, stochastic-processes

I am reading the one lecture note [Dynamics for Spherical Models of Spin-Glass and Aging](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-40908-3_5).

On page 126. In the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick (SK) model, we suppose that there are $N$ people labeled as $[N]:=\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, $\sigma \in \{+1,-1\}^N$. Let $\mathbf{J}=(J_{ij})_{1\le i, j\le N}$ be symmetric and let $J_{ij}$ be a centered independent random variable such that
$$
E[J_{ij}^2]=1/n, \,  E[J_{ii}^2]=2/n,
$$
often assumed to be Gaussian for simplicity. Assume that $x_0$ is independent of $\mathbf{J}$.

If $\{\lambda_i\}_{1\le i\le N}$ denotes the eigenvalue of $\mathbf{J}=\{J_{ij}\}$, then for a vector $\mathbf{x}_0$,
$$
\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, e^{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{x}_0\rangle=^d\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_0\rangle\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2
$$
where $u$ is independent of $\lambda_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_0$, and follows the law of the sphere $S_{\sqrt{N}}^{N-1}$ with radius $\sqrt{N}$.

***(I think $u$ follows the law of the unit sphere?)***

---

From the Weak law of large numbers, the first term
$$
\frac1N\langle x_0, x_0\rangle\to \int x^2d\mu(x)
$$
as $n\to \infty$.

The main question is as follows.

> Question: Why do we have
> $$
> \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2=\int e^{\lambda}d\sigma(\lambda)
> $$

From semi-circle law, we have the empirical measure $\frac{1}{N}\sum \delta_{\lambda_i}\to \sigma(dx)=C\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$. But how to get the above limit? I think there is missing the scaling $1/N$ on the left-hand side.

---

I try to show that
$$
law(\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, e^{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{x}_0\rangle)=law(\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_0\rangle\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2)
$$

Let $\mathbf{J}=G^*DG$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Then $e^\mathbf{J}$ can be expressed via spectral decomposition as
$$
e^\mathbf{J}=G^Te^{D}G=\sum e^{\lambda_i} s_is_i^T
$$
(the second one is wrong?)
where $s_i\in R^N$ are eigenvectors of $\mathbf{J}$ and $G=[s_1,\dots, s_N]$.

I am confused about where $u_i^2$ comes from? If we plug in the spectral decomposition, it becomes that
$$
\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, e^{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{x}_0\rangle=\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \sum e^{\lambda_i} s_is_i^T\mathbf{x}_0\rangle
$$

Here
$$
E[\sum e^{\lambda_i} s_is_i^T]=E[\frac{1}{N}I]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector components $u_i$ have zero mean and variance $1/N$ (since $\sum_i u_i^2=1$); they are independent of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. We therefore have the expectation value
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2\right]=\lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}\right]=\int e^{\lambda}d\sigma(\lambda)=I_2(2),$$
with $p(\lambda)=d\sigma(\lambda)/d\lambda=(2\pi)^{-1}\sqrt{4-\lambda^2}\,\mathbb{1}_{[-2,2]}(\lambda)$ the semi-circular probability distribution of the eigenvalues (normalized to unity).

Fluctuations arond the expectation value are smaller by a factor $1/\sqrt N$ and may be neglected in the large-$N$ limit.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why do we need to take expectations? In the first equality, you use $E[u_i^2]=1/N$. Also, since $\sum u_i^2=1$, why its variance is $1/N$? The second equality also holds without the expectation right? This is from semi-circle law.

Comment: Can you see my latest update? I am confused about where $u_i^2$ comes from? If we do spectral decomposition, we will have eigenvector but not square of i-th component of eigenvectors.

Comment: 1) the desired equation only makes sense in expectation, because you are equating a fluctuating quantity with a deterministic value; fluctuations are small, so it does make sense to take the expectation value; 2) the expectation value of $u_i^2$ is independent of $i$ and summed over all $i$ from 1 to $N$ equals 1, hence $\mathbb{E}[u_i^2]=1/N$; 3) yes, the second equality is just the semicircle law for large $N$.

Comment: your latest update: write $e^J=\sum_i e^{\lambda_i} s_i^\top s_i$, then the $N\times N$ matrix $s_i^\top s_i$ reduces to $N^{-1}$ times the unit matrix in expectation --- off-diagonal elements average to zero, and the diagonal elements average to a constant, which equals $1/N$ because the trace of the matrix is $s_is_i^\top=1$.

Comment: I switched $\top$, replace $s_i^\top s_i$ by $s_i s_i^\top$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean $
E[\sum e^{\lambda_i} s_is_i^T]=E[\frac{1}{N}I]
$? Why off-diagonal elements goes to zero? I can understand the diagonal entries because $Tr(s_is_i^T)=1$ from the orthogonal property of $s_i\in R^N$. But how to get $e^J=\sum e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2$ from this fact?

Comment: right, $E[s_is_i^T]=\frac{1}{N}I$; for large $N$ the elements of the eigenvectors are i.i.d. Gaussians with mean zero and variance $1/N$, so all off-diagonal elements average to zero; because the eigenvectors are independent of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ you can average separately.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there is a typo in $
\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, e^{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{x}_0\rangle=\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_0\rangle\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i^2
$? Is it equal to $\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_0\rangle\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}u_i u_i^T$?

Comment: I mean if they are equal in law. It seems that they are not equal.

Comment: I cannot make sense of this equation with the $u_i^2$, unless I take expectation values and replace $u_i^2$ by $1/N$; I presume that is what the authors mean.

Comment: Ok, it makes now. So you think that should be $
E[\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, e^{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{x}_0\rangle]=E[\frac{1}{N}\langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_0\rangle \frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\lambda_i}]
$. But why $u_i$ is mean 0? If it is mean zero, then $E[u_i u_j]=E[u_i]E[u_j]=0$ and $E[u_i^2]=1/N$ for the i-th component of eigenvector $u$.

Comment: the matrix of eigenvectors is uniformly distributed with the Haar measure in the unitary group $U(N)$, that is why the mean of each element is zero.

Comment: So that means the eigenvectors $u$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere and it can be represented by a $N(0,1)$ Gaussian $g$ by $u=g/\|g\|$?